# sqlalchemy copy contents of relationship collection

Tags: python, collections, reference, sqlalchemy, relationship

I have a table which has a relationship. It looks something like this:

```
class User(Base)
    userId = Column(TEXT, primary_key=True)

    products = relationship('Products', backref=backref('Products'))
```

After loading, I end up with a collection attached to the User object containing all the products which are related to that user. Great! Just what I wanted! I then attempt to copy this collection from one user to another. This fails. When I attempt to set the reference of the 2nd user to the 1st collection, it succeeds, but it DELETES the reference from the first user! This makes absolutely no sense to me. It looks something like the below:

```
user1.products
>>>> InstrumentedList[product1, product2]
user2.products
>>>> InstrumentedList[]

user2.products = user1.products

user1.products
>>>>[]
user2.products
>>>>[product1, product2]
```

This appears to violate everything I know about how references work in python. Assignment of the a reference to a collection should not affect other existing references. Can anyone please shed light on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the problem here. The problem is that I was attempting to assign objects with a one to many relationship in a many to many relationship context. A product can only have one user, so when one assigns a product to a user, the previous relationship is removed. The manner in which this is represented in a collection makes this pretty confusing.